# Can we create a custom log file in apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, aem

With Apache 2.2, we were using below-

```
RewriteLog "/etc/httpd/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 1
```

and

```
RewriteLog "logs/rewrite_test1.log"
 RewriteLogLevel 1
```

How to replace them in Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Apache HTTP documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging), it looks like Rewrite Logs are now included into error log from which you need to extract the data:

> Those familiar with earlier versions of mod_rewrite will no doubt be looking for the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directives. This functionality has been completely replaced by the new per-module logging configuration mentioned above.
>   To get just the mod_rewrite-specific log messages, pipe the log file through grep:
>   tail -f error_log|fgrep '[rewrite:'d.

The path to error log can be defined in this way ([more info there](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog)):

ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"

To control rewrite log level you can use [LogLevel Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel) like this:

> Example: LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3